# Дан массив целых чисел. Записать в этот же массив сначала все положительные, затем все отрицательные числа и нули, сохраняя порядок их следования

Tags: python

```
num = [-1, 23, -35, -54,0, 233, -7, -1023, -342, 234, ]
minus = []
plus = []
zero = []
for i in num:
    if (i < 0):
        minus.append(i)
    elif (i == 0):
        zero.append(i)
    else:
        plus.append(i)

num.append(plus)
num.append(minus)
num.append(zero)
print(num)
```

Comment: Так а в чем вопрос?

Comment: На выходе получается список, в котором ещё 3 списка, в которых положительные, отрицательные, нуль, может есть способ написать по-другому?

Comment: `append` -> `extend` во второй группе. И не надо портить исходный список. Создайте новый.

Answer (score 6):

В целом правильный код, не нужны только `append()` в конце

```
num = [-1, 23, -35, -54, 0, 233, -7, -1023, -342, 234]
plus, minus, zero = [], [], []
for i in num:
    if i < 0:
        minus.append(i)
    elif i == 0:
        zero.append(i)
    else:
        plus.append(i)

num = plus + minus + zero # здесь не нужен append(), иначе получатся вложенные списки
print(num)
```

Можно сделать покороче с использованием `filter()`

```
num = [-1, 23, -35, -54, 0, 233, -7, -1023, -342, 234]
num = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, num)) + list(filter(lambda x: x < 0, num)) + list(filter(lambda x: x == 0, num))
print(num)
```

Или с помощью `спискового включения (List comprehension)`

```
num = [-1, 23, -35, -54, 0, 233, -7, -1023, -342, 234]
num = [x for x in num if x > 0] + [x for x in num if x < 0] + [x for x in num if x == 0]
print(num)
```

```
[23, 233, 234, -1, -35, -54, -7, -1023, -342, 0]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Добро пожаловать на  Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

можно сделать через сортировку:

```
arr = sorted(num, key=lambda x: 0 if x > 0 else 1 if x < 0 else 2)
```

или чуть-чуть покороче:

```
arr = sorted(num, key=lambda x: ((2, 1)[x < 0], 0)[x > 0])
```

правда есть вопрос может ли смениться порядок внутри групп (положительных, отрицательных), поэтому можно гарантированную сортировку:

```
arr = [a[1] for a in sorted(enumerate(num), key=lambda x: (0 if x[1] > 0 else 1 if x[1] < 0 else 2, x[0]))]
```

но вроде и без этого работать будет

Comment: Как я понял, разбиение на две группы - положительные и все остальные: `key=lambda x: x <= 0`.

Comment: да, группировка как бы по двум группам получается тогда `False` и `True`

Comment: Для трёх групп есть такой трюк: `key=lambda x: (x < 0) - (0 < x)`.

Comment: да, красивое условие

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy интересный подход. Порядок следования групп с таким условием будет `>0`, затем `0`, затем `<0`? Для последовательности `>0`, `<0`, `0`, как я понимаю, потребуется модификация условия

Comment: Для порядка `+, -, 0`: `lambda x: (x == 0) - (x > 0)`.

Comment: "гарантированную сортировку" не надо делать. В Питоне сортировка стабильная - не меняет порядок равных элементов. Это гарантировано: [Sort Stability and Complex Sorts](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts).

Answer (score 3):

можно использовать такой ключ при сортировке:

```
sorted(num, key=lambda x: (x==0,x<0))  # [23, 233, 234, -1, -35, -54, -7, -1023, -342, 0]
```